# Gradle Error: No value has been specified for property 'buildConfigPackageName'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When I attempt to build my android project after updating to the latest version of android studio/developer tools I have been getting these errors:

> [Fatal Error] :1:38: A pseudo attribute name is expected.
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem was found with the configuration of task ':apoAppAndroid:generatePharmoreDebugBuildConfig'.
>   No value has been specified for property 'buildConfigPackageName'.

I though Package Name had been deprecated, what am I doing wrong?

Here is a shortened version of my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "20"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bluechilli.apoappandroid"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 19

}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("../../../.android/debug.keystore")
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword "android"
    }
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

productFlavors{
    basic{
        applicationId "com.bluechilli.basic"

    }
    pharmore{
        applicationId "com.bluechilli.pharmore"
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I also have the same use in my gradle file.

Comment: I have fixed it by removing product flavours from the build.  Didn't work out what was really going wrong.

Comment: have you defined the packagename in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yeah I have defined the package name

Comment: Check for any invalid characters in your AndroidManifest.xml.  In my case, it was a merge issue from git that had things like: <<<<<<< HEAD

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to create a fresh project and transfer all your code over (**excluding your old package name**). I had similar problems before, but resolved most with just copying over my code to a new project. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

in fact you don't need to define packagename in AndroidManifest ,  just add it in build.gradle .